# Orthographic camera zoom with focus on a specific point

Tags: unity-game-engine, orthographic

I have an orthographic camera and would like to implement a zoom feature to a specific point. I.e., imagine you have a picture and want to zoom to a specific part of the picture.

I know how to zoom in, the problem is to move the camera to a position that has the desired zone in focus.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

The camera's `orthographicSize` is the number of world space units in the top half of the viewport. If it's 0.5, then a 1 unit cube will exactly fill the viewport (vertically).

So to zoom in on your target region, center your camera on it (by setting (x,y) to the target's center) and set `orthographicSize` to half the region's height.

Here is an example to center and zoom to the extents of an object. (Zoom with LMB; 'R' to reset.)

```
public class OrthographicZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 defaultCenter;
    private float defaultHeight; // height of orthographic viewport in world units

    private void Start()
    {
        defaultCenter = camera.transform.position;
        defaultHeight = 2f*camera.orthographicSize;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Collider target = GetTarget();
            if(target != null)
                OrthoZoom(target.bounds.center, target.bounds.size.y); // Could directly set orthographicSize = bounds.extents.y
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
            OrthoZoom(defaultCenter, defaultHeight);
    }


    private void OrthoZoom(Vector2 center, float regionHeight)
    {
        camera.transform.position = new Vector3(center.x, center.y, defaultCenter.z);
        camera.orthographicSize = regionHeight/2f;
    }


    private Collider GetTarget()
    {
        var hit = new RaycastHit();
        Physics.Raycast(camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit);
        return hit.collider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope you find this code example useful, should be a copy / paste.
Note: this script assume it's attached to the camera object, otherwise you should adjust the transform to the camera object reference.

```
private float lastZoomDistance = float.PositiveInfinity; // remember that this should   be reset to infinite on touch end
private float maxZoomOut = 200;
private float maxZoomIn = 50;
private float zoomSpeed = 2;

void Update() {

if (Input.touchCount >= 2) {

    Vector2 touch0, touch1;
    float distance;
    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    touch0 = Input.GetTouch(0).position - pos;
    touch1 = Input.GetTouch(1).position - pos;

    zoomCenter = (touch0 + touch1) / 2;

    distance = Vector2.Distance(touch0, touch1);
    if(lastZoomDistance == float.PositiveInfinity) {
        lastZoomDistance = distance;
    } else {
        if(distance > lastZoomDistance && camera.orthographicSize + zoomSpeed <= maxZoomOut) {
            this.camera.orthographicSize = this.camera.orthographicSize + zoomSpeed;
            // Assuming script is attached to camera - otherwise, change the transform.position to the camera object
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, zoomCenter, Time.deltaTime);
        } else if(distance < lastZoomDistance && camera.orthographicSize - zoomSpeed >= maxZoomIn) {
            this.camera.orthographicSize = this.camera.orthographicSize - zoomSpeed;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, zoomCenter, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    lastZoomDistance = distance;
}

}
```